# SQL Union as Subquery to create Date Ranges from Start Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, union

I have three tabels, each of them has a date column (the date column is an INT field and needs to stay that way). I need a UNION accross all three tables so that I get the list of unique dates in accending order like this:

```
20040602  
20051215  
20060628  
20100224  
20100228  
20100422  
20100512  
20100615
```

Then I need to add a column to the result of the query where I subtract one from each date and place it one row above as the end date. Basically I need to generate the end date from the start date somehow and this is what I got so far (not working):

```
With Query1 As (
    Select date_one As StartDate
    From table_one
     Union
     Select date_two As StartDate
     From table_two
     Union
     Select date_three e As StartDate
     From table_three
     Order By Date Asc
     )
Select Query1.StartDate - 1 As EndDate
From Query1
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are you positive that column is a Date or DateTime data type, and not an INT?

Comment: I don't think your query will even run. You can't use `ORDER BY` in a CTE.

Comment: @HardCode both is correct, it's an int field and the query does not work yet.

Comment: -1 because "each of them has a date column" followed by comment from same author saying: " it's an int field".... Someone invented an "edit" option for that!

Comment: @Luuk you're right, I'm sorry. I have edited by post.

Comment: ok, i did undo the '-1' 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on your existing `union` cte, we can use `lead()` in the outer query to get the `start_date` of the next record, and withdraw `1` from it.

```
with q as (
    select date_one start_date  from table_one
    union select date_two from table_two
    union select date_three from table_three
)
select 
    start_date,
    dateadd(day, -1, lead(start_date) over(order by start_date)) end_date
from q
order by start_date
```

If the datatype the original columns are numeric, then you need to do some casting before applying date functions:

```
with q as (
    select cast(cast(date_one as varchar(8)) as date) start_date  from table_one
    union select cast(cast(date_two as varchar(8)) as date) from table_two
    union select cast(cast(date_three as varchar(8)) as date) from table_three
)
select 
    start_date,
    dateadd(day, -1, lead(start_date) over(order by start_date)) end_date
from q
order by start_date
```

Comment: The only thing to be weary of here is returning an invalid date for your end date.  Since the OP stated that it is an integer column you could return something like 20200300 as an end_date, if your start_date was 20200301.  Not sure what the requirements are, but it may mean converting to a date field, doing a dateadd operation to remove the day then converting back to an int field.

Comment: @ChadEstes: yes I just read that in the comment, and updated my answer with additional casting.

Comment: @GMB thanks! It has worked perfectly. The only problem is that at the end I'll need it as int like this "20040602" - how do I convert it back?

Comment: Converting this date back can be done with `format(start_date,'yyyyMMdd')`   [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)